# Cannot modify /lib on Gentoo live image

Tags: gentoo, live-usb, readonly

I am trying to install Gentoo on my laptop. The wifi included is not supported by the Linux kernel, so I found a driver for it. When I went to install the driver to `/lib/modules/...`, I got the error: `Cannot do xyz, read-only file system.` However, I can write to anything other than `/lib`.

This problem occurs in the live/install image. I do not know if it appears after the install (I need internet on the laptop to proceed through the install process).

This does not happen in live images for other distributions.

Answer (score 0):

Some of the Gentoo install media use a squashfs filesystem, that's read-only, and selectively mount an overlayfs for writes. Likely it can be tweaked to fix your needs.

In the meantime, you can also just mount an overlayfs on /lib/modules/ yourself.

What install media did you use? Let me know and I'll either just fix it or pass it on to the right people.

Comment: I realised that I can use the Live USB with a desktop environment to make it work. Thanks though.